# What to set the testdevices in firebase-admob (targetinfo) when releasing the app with ads in flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

I am developing a app and i am integrating ads into it.

Initially i am specifying the test devices as my app id which i got from the logs.

But when i removed the app id from test devices and set the testdevices as null in the target info. The ads are not showing up in the debug mode or apk (created using "flutter build apk")

The ads are working fine for both test and real ad units when i am using the app id in the test devices.

So, can anyone please tell me how to release the app with ads in flutter(what to set the testdevices during release).

There are no proper instructions on the web.